# How do I make a driver change a rig's porportions globally?

Tags: rigging, drivers

So even standing or laying this driver would determine the rig's total height percentage.

How do I set up a vertical bone I can use as a driver that affects a rigged character to change the vertical height no matter the rig's pose?

Comment: You could drive the rig objects z dimension, but I don't think could do it with a bone within the rig,... , certainly with a global empty.  Interesting idea, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @batFINGER I tried using a deformer mesh modifier to scale but it doesn't work as the bones cause a pulling distortion as they aren't being scaled.